# Ошибка в реализации алгоритма поиска кратчайшего пути

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика

Задача: 
Задано поле m на n. На нем отмечена стартовая позиция (буквой "s") и позиция, в которую нужно попасть (буква "f"). Каждая клетка поля может быть либо пустой (обозначается точкой), либо содержать в себе преграду (означает, что через эту клетку нельзя пройти, обозначается как #). Необходимо вывести минимальное время, за которое исполнитель может дойти от стартовой до финишной позиции. Время считается исходя из следующих условий: 1) исполнитель имеет направление движения, поворот на 90 градусов занимает 1 секунду; 2)шаг вперед занимает 1 секунду.

Мое решение выглядит следующим образом:

1. Создаем новую матрицу, такого же размера, как и во входных данных. В конечном итоге в каждой клетке будет храниться минимальное время, необходимое, чтобы добраться в данную клетку. Изначально заполняем ее "бесконечностями" (`math.inf`). Единственное исключение составляют клетки-преграды, в них кладем бесконечно маленькое число `(Decimal('-Infinity'))`.
2. Находим стартовую клетку (клетку, где находится символ "s"), запоминаем ее координаты. Вызываем рекурсивную функцию (`count_neighbors`), передаем ей координаты стартовой точки. Функция проверяет всех соседей точки (сверху, снизу, справа, слева), координаты который были ей переданы. Если выясняется, что через текущую точку в точку-соседа можно добраться за меньшее время по сравнению с тем, которое уже в ней хранится, то изменяем это время на новое значение и рекурсивно запускаемся от этой точки (поэтому изначально в точки-преграды кладем бесконечно маленькое число, чтобы такие точки не обрабатывались и не учитывались). Таким образом, после завершения работы данной функции каждая точка матрицы будет содержать минимальное время, за которое можно в нее добраться.
3. Далее находим координаты финишной точки и смотрим на время, если оно равно бесконечности - выводим "-1" (что означает, что пути не существует), иначе выводим это время.

Пример входных и выходных данных:

```
Input: 
3 3
s..
###
..f

Output:
-1


Input:
3 3
s..
...
..f

Output:
5
```

Ограничение по памяти: 256 Мб

Ограничение по времени: 15 с

При сдаче на тестировщик мое решение проходит 17 из 25 тестов (все ответы правильные, 8 тестов не проходят, так как во время выполнения программа завершается с ненулевым кодом возврата (runtime error)).

Код моего решения:

```
from math import inf
from pprint import pprint
import copy
from decimal import Decimal

# 2 - start
# 3 - finish
# 1 - empty
# 0 - not empty

# directions: 1 - up, 2 - down, 3 - right, 4 - left

table = list()
n, m = map(int, input().split())

tops = [[dict() for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
start_matrix = list()


def check_input_str(s):
    s_copy = copy.deepcopy(s)

    deleted_symbols = list()

    for symbol in s:
        if symbol not in ['#', '.', 's', 'f'] and symbol not in deleted_symbols:
            s_copy = s_copy.replace(symbol, '')
            deleted_symbols.append(symbol)

    return s_copy


def read_data():
    for i in range(n):
        data = list(check_input_str(input()))
        start_matrix.append(data)


def fill_table():
    start_coordinates = 0, 0
    finish_coordinates = 0, 0

    for i in range(len(start_matrix)):
        table.append([inf for j in range(len(start_matrix[i]))])

    for i in range(len(table)):
        for j in range(len(table[i])):
            if start_matrix[i][j] == 's':
                start_coordinates = i, j

                if start_coordinates != (0, 0) and finish_coordinates != (0, 0):
                    break

            elif start_matrix[i][j] == 'f':
                finish_coordinates = i, j

                if start_coordinates != (0, 0) and finish_coordinates != (0, 0):
                    break

        if start_coordinates != (0, 0) and finish_coordinates != (0, 0):
            break

    for i in range(len(start_matrix)):
        for j in range(len(start_matrix[i])):
            if start_matrix[i][j] != '#':
                tops[i][j] = {'time': inf, 'direction': 0}
            else:
                tops[i][j] = {'time': Decimal('-Infinity'), 'direction': 0}

    tops[start_coordinates[0]][start_coordinates[1]]['direction'] = 2
    tops[start_coordinates[0]][start_coordinates[1]]['time'] = 0
    table[start_coordinates[0]][start_coordinates[1]] = 0

    count_neighbors(start_coordinates)

    if tops[finish_coordinates[0]][finish_coordinates[1]]['time'] == inf:
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(tops[finish_coordinates[0]][finish_coordinates[1]]['time'])


def count_neighbors(coordinates):
    i, j = coordinates[0], coordinates[1]

    value = tops[i][j]['time']
    direction = tops[i][j]['direction']

    if 0 <= i + 1 < len(table) and start_matrix[i + 1][j] != '#' and start_matrix[i + 1][j] != 's':
        if direction == 1:
            if value + 3 < table[i + 1][j]:
                table[i + 1][j] = value + 3
                tops[i + 1][j]['time'] = value + 3
                tops[i + 1][j]['direction'] = 2

                count_neighbors((i + 1, j))

        elif direction == 2:
            if value + 1 < table[i + 1][j]:
                table[i + 1][j] = value + 1
                tops[i + 1][j]['time'] = value + 1
                tops[i + 1][j]['direction'] = 2

                count_neighbors((i + 1, j))

        elif direction == 3 or direction == 4:
            if value + 2 < table[i + 1][j]:
                table[i + 1][j] = value + 2
                tops[i + 1][j]['time'] = value + 2
                tops[i + 1][j]['direction'] = 2

                count_neighbors((i + 1, j))

    if 0 <= i - 1 < len(table) and start_matrix[i - 1][j] != '#' and start_matrix[i - 1][j] != 's':
        if direction == 1:
            if value + 1 < table[i - 1][j]:
                table[i - 1][j] = value + 1
                tops[i - 1][j]['time'] = value + 1
                tops[i - 1][j]['direction'] = 1

                count_neighbors((i - 1, j))

        elif direction == 2:
            if value + 3 < table[i - 1][j]:
                table[i - 1][j] = value + 3
                tops[i - 1][j]['time'] = value + 3
                tops[i - 1][j]['direction'] = 1

                count_neighbors((i - 1, j))

        elif direction == 3 or direction == 4:
            if value + 2 < table[i - 1][j]:
                table[i - 1][j] = value + 2
                tops[i - 1][j]['time'] = value + 2
                tops[i - 1][j]['direction'] = 1

                count_neighbors((i - 1, j))

    if 0 <= j + 1 < len(table[i]) and start_matrix[i][j + 1] != '#' and start_matrix[i][j + 1] != 's':
        if direction == 3:
            if value + 1 < table[i][j + 1]:
                table[i][j + 1] = value + 1
                tops[i][j + 1]['time'] = value + 1
                tops[i][j + 1]['direction'] = 3

                count_neighbors((i, j + 1))

        elif direction == 4:
            if value + 3 < table[i][j + 1]:
                table[i][j + 1] = value + 3
                tops[i][j + 1]['time'] = value + 3
                tops[i][j + 1]['direction'] = 3

                count_neighbors((i, j + 1))

        elif direction == 1 or direction == 2:
            if value + 2 < table[i][j + 1]:
                table[i][j + 1] = value + 2
                tops[i][j + 1]['time'] = value + 2
                tops[i][j + 1]['direction'] = 3

                count_neighbors((i, j + 1))

    if 0 <= j - 1 < len(table[i]) and start_matrix[i][j - 1] != '#' and start_matrix[i][j - 1] != 's':
        if direction == 4:
            if value + 1 < table[i][j - 1]:
                table[i][j - 1] = value + 1
                tops[i][j - 1]['time'] = value + 1
                tops[i][j - 1]['direction'] = 4

                count_neighbors((i, j - 1))

        elif direction == 3:
            if value + 3 < table[i][j - 1]:
                table[i][j - 1] = value + 3
                tops[i][j - 1]['time'] = value + 3
                tops[i][j - 1]['direction'] = 4

                count_neighbors((i, j - 1))

        elif direction == 1 or direction == 2:
            if value + 2 < table[i][j - 1]:
                table[i][j - 1] = value + 2
                tops[i][j - 1]['time'] = value + 2
                tops[i][j - 1]['direction'] = 4

                count_neighbors((i, j - 1))


read_data()
fill_table()
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Да, изначально исполнитель смотрит вниз.

Comment: Какие ограничения на размер поля? Возможно, у Вас рекурсия банально переполняет стек.

Comment: Да, как оказалось, стандартной глубины рекурсии не хватает, пришлось увеличивать.